# SQLite DB Blob field Vs Android Filesystem

Tags: android, image, sqlite, blob

Here's the thing that's causing a bit of headscratching, maybe someone can shed some light on the situation. I'm using the Camera intent to snap a picture (well, any number of pictures really), like so:

```
    ImageView imgPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgButtonPhoto);
    imgPhoto.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(71,117,255));
    imgPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            ++snapNumber; 

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            lastPicSaved = String.valueOf(gd.getDeliveryId()) + "_" + String.valueOf(snapNumber) + ".jpg";
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), lastPicSaved));             

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, GooseConsts.IMAGE_CAPTURE_INTENT);           
        }
    });
```

Once the activity has finished I snag the result like so:

```
    case GooseConsts.IMAGE_CAPTURE_INTENT:
        try 
        {
            String newCompressedImage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + lastPicSaved;

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;   
            //options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newCompressedImage, options);
            FileOutputStream fos;

            fos = new FileOutputStream(newCompressedImage);
            b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fos);

            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            Image i = new Image();
            i.setReported(0);
            i.setReportedFull(0);
            i.setImage(newCompressedImage);
            //i.setImageData(b);

            dbHelper.insertImageReference(i, gd.getDeliveryId());   
    }
```

Simple stuff really. As you can see I'm using the `options.inSampleSize` and reducing quality upon compression, to reduce the size of the end image, so as to maintain a small image capture to send back to hq, via an XMPP packet.

**Here comes the fun part!**
On the filesystem this resulting image is around the 50Kb size, possibly a bit more but never more than 60Kb. Which is fine, that sends via XMPP and I can process and display it in a custom connected client I've also written.

I figured it'd probably be best to keep the images, just in case sending fails for whatever reason, but didn't want them getting lost in the file system, so added a `BLOB` field to my local device database. I wondered if I could just send them directly from said DB and do away with the file system completely, so I tried it, suddenly **NO** images were being sent/received by my client bot. Strange! After a bit of digging, I noticed that the images that had been saved into the db `BLOB` are now (amazingly) 3x the size of the original. Same dimensions (486x684) and same quality (as I've adb pulled a few to test against the ones stored on the SD card).

Can anyone tell me why this is the case? I've been using BLOB fields for years and have never seen such a dramatic increase in file size before. A couple of Kb here and there, sure, but not jumping from 50(ish)Kb to over 160Kb?!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you compress the image convert the Image to a byte array instead of using a blob

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newCompressedImage, options);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, stream);
byte [] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

This should keep the file size to a minimum. You will have to convert the byte array back to a bitmap for display, of course. But that should be straight forward.

I believe byte array's have a size limit though. Initialize it instead as

```
byte [] byteArray = new byte [1024];
// then
byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Would you suggest doing this rather than say, storing a path reference in the DB and just falling back to using the file system? I could be dealing with thousands of images a week, and would rather keep a small footprint on the device, rather than bloat a db, if it comes to that ofc.

Comment: Not really, primarily because if the Images are not stored in a private share you can't guarantee that the file is still on the device. For example, the user deletes the image. This would cause unexpected crashes. but then again you could create a private share folder and keep them in that instead of in the public file system.